# UWP Certificate Expired - Can't generate a new one

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms UWP that is currently in use, but since the certificate has expired no new installations can be done.

Google and SO keeps directing to me just create a new test certificate from the packaging tab of the app manifest in VS, but when I try to install the package with that the generated certificate I keep getting an error message that reads

> The certificate does not match the one used to sign the package or bundle

Any suggestions?

I think the issue might be that I'm trying to create a new certificate on a machine different from the one that was originally used to sign the package. I'll see if I can get a hold of the original machine tomorrow and see if that can give any clarity on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to install the side load package you already have, you could check the expiry date of the certificate with which the package is signed (it should be available in the package properties). Refer to this screenshot for details https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1KA7.png. Change your system date to be within the certificate's valid window and it should enable you to install the older package you have. Once installed you could change the date again to match the current date.

However, if your goal is to get the existing package signed with new certificate, you might have to unpack it using `makeappx.exe`, change the Publisher details in the `AppManifest` to match the new certificate you have created, repack it (again using `makeappx.exe`) and then you should be able to sign it with this new certificate and install it. This should work.